# Filter out specific errors from Flake8 results

Tags: python, databricks, flake8

We are writing notebooks in databricks. When we put them to git we want to run flake8 on them to check for new problems in the code.

As databricks has some predefined variables those are undefined in the code itself.
Is it possible to filter our errors like:

```
F821 undefined name 'dbutils'
```

While keeping errors like

```
F821 undefined name 'my_var'
```

I am aware of the `--ignore parameter`, but as far as I understand this would only allow to exclude F821 in general and not for a specific variable name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an additional list of builtins by using the [`builtins` parameter / configuration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-builtins):

```py
$ cat t2.py 
db_utils.wat()
my_var.wat()
```

```
$ flake8 t2.py 
t2.py:1:1: F821 undefined name 'db_utils'
t2.py:2:1: F821 undefined name 'my_var'
$ flake8 t2.py  --builtins db_utils
t2.py:2:1: F821 undefined name 'my_var'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the beginning of the notebook

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
```

Optionally, install `databricks-connect` instead of `pyspark` in your local environment so that `pyspark.dbutils` is known. (Flake8 does not check, but other tools like VS Code's Pylance do.)

This also gives code completion in external editors (VS Code in the following screenshot):

[image: VS Code code completion]

Comment: tbh: adding boilerplate code to every notebook just for syntax checkers to run is not a good idea

Comment: Arguably, the bad idea is to provide a runtime environment pre-populated with variables in a way intransparent to standard tools. :-) I added a hint and screenshot with code completion in the answer to underline the benefits of declaring variables in Python code.